# how to show two table rows together using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have two table in mysql phpmyadmin

1) **attend**

1. user_name
2. date
3. checkin

2) **attendout**

1. user_name
2. date
3. checkout

here is a table

```
attend table
_____________________________________________________
user_name | date     |  checkin 

  abcd   |   10-5-2015 | 2:00  
  xyz    |   10-5-2015 | 3:00 


attendout table
_____________________________________________________
user_name | date     |  checkout

  abcd   |   10-5-2015 | 5:00
  xyz    |   10-5-2015 | 6:00
```

i want result like this

```
_____________________________________________________
 User    | Date      |  Check in |  Check out
  abcd   | 10-5-2015 | 2:00      | 5:00 
  xyz    | 10-5-2015 | 3:00      | 6:00
```

here is mysql code

```
 $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT attend.user_name,attend.date,attend.checkin, attendout.checkout ".
 "FROM attend, attendout ".
    "WHERE attend.date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b' = attendout.date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b'");
```

plz help me to fix it

Comment: Is it always one to one ? Is it possible that for the same date in `attendout` there could be multiple entry for the same user ?

Comment: it is always one and yes it is showing multiple entry for same user but i want single entry in attendout and attend in

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple join:

```
SELECT attend.user_name,attend.date,attend.checkin, attendout.checkout ".
 "FROM attend join  attendout on attend.user_name=attendout.user_name ".
    "WHERE attend.date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b' = attendout.date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b'
```

But stop using deprecated `mysql_` API use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`with prepared statements.

Comment: what if a user has multiple check in,checkouts ?

Answer (score 1):

IF there is always a 1-1 entry in the system i.e. one entry for checkout for checkin for one date then you should try the left join as follows

```
SELECT at.user, at.date, at.checkin, ao.checkout from attend at LEFT JOIN  attendout ao  ON at.date = ao.date
```

The where condition is also optional. You might or might not add it.

Comment: not working it is showing Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: why don't you directly try firing the query in phpmyadmin sql window and see if there is any result and I can help you more @user3000993

Comment: it is showing no result and it is showing error i am using this and it is showing same error SELECT attend.user_name, attend.date, attend.checkin, attendout.checkout from attend at LEFT JOIN  attendout  ON attend.date = attendout.date

Comment: see you are making a very basic mistake in using the alias or object please correct that... Thats a sql syntax error @user3000993

Comment: any luck until now @user3000993? if you share the error or progress can help more

Comment: @PreetiMaurya .. UNION ALL is best way as per my concern

Answer (score 0):

you have to use inner join.

```
 SELECT * FROM attend
 INNER JOIN attendout
 ON attend.user_name=attendout.user_name
 ORDER BY attend.user_name
```

Comment: i am using this but result is repeating two time SELECT attend.user_name, attend.date, attend.checkin, attendout.checkout FROM attend INNER JOIN attendout ON attend.user_name=attendout.user_name ORDER BY attend.user_name

Comment: use SELECT attend.user_name, attendout.checkout, date, checkin

Answer (score 0):

It may work fine

```
SELECT user_name,date,checkin,NULL
FROM attend
UNION ALL
SELECT user_name,date,NULL,checkout
FROM attendout
```